# Is there a way to manipulate all rows in a database table with Python/Pandas?

Tags: python, html, pandas

I wrote the content of a bunch of `HTML` files into a `SQL` Database. 
The content of each file is divided into 80-90 rows in the Database.

Now I want to filter the `HTML` files and write the results in another Table.
The filters I am going for are the title of the article in the `HTML` file ( so filtering for h1 tags), the actual content of the article in the file and the tags give by the author.

I have thousands of `HTML` files in the database table (so approx. 15000 rows).

Is there a way to search and filter the e.g. title (so looking for the h1 tag) for each article in the database table with `Python/Pandas`?

I have already seen some solutions with `BeautifulSoup`, but just with one `HTML` file.

So I am looking for a solution that lets me loop through the database table.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = df[ df['column_name'].str.contains('h1') ]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer.
The Code works, but the h1 tags are not filtered. The html file stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, you can use pandas to get the required subset of a dataset.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file_name')
# Now you manipulate this df object
df = df[ df['attribute'].str.contains('h1') ]
# Further manipulations with this df object
```